# Which actions in past games affect War Assets in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-series

In assessing my War Assets from the Normandy's war room, I'm already seeing the results of my decisions in past games.

For instance, the First, Third, and Fifth fleets are at diminished strength after saving the Council from Sovereign in Mass Effect 1 (Paragon Ending), and the Marine 103 division is at reduced strength because I did not complete The Arrival DLC in Mass Effect 2.

What decisions in the past two games directly affect War Assets in the third?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Kasumi, Jacob, Miranda, Zaeed, Jack, Grunt, and Samara can all be recruited as war assets if they survived ME2 and events in ME3.
- The strength of the Normandy is effected by the amount of upgrades applied in ME2
- Having a lot of mineral resources at the end of ME2 may grant you a bonus of up to 100 war assets.
- The Destiny Ascension can be added as a war asset provided it survived ME1.  This reduces the strength of all of the Alliance fleets.
- If the Destiny Ascension was destroyed, the strength of the Alliance fleets are boosted, and a new Alliance Admiral is available.
- Zhu's hope colonist are a war asset if they survived ME1.
- The Rachni can be recruited as assets if you allowed the queen to live in ME1.
- Conrad Verner can even provide a war asset provided you did a bunch
  of random completionist quests in ME1
- Wrex and Mordin surviving ME 1 and 2 and what Mordin did with the genophage data have a big effect on the amount of war assets that can be generated from the Korgan.
- If you did not complete Arrival, the a Alliance 103rd marine division is weakened.
- Captain Kirrahe can bring in elements of the STG provided he survived
  Virmire.
- If you completed Bring Down the Sky and the Batarian leader escaped,
  he can be recruited to strengthen what's left of their fleet.
- The Archer bothers are available as assets if they survived Overlord.
- Destroying/not destroying the Collector Base effects the value of an asset found in the Cerberus base.
- If Kelly Chambers survives ME2 she can help recruit some ex-Cerberus engineers.
- Reprogramming the Geth Heretics increases the strength of their fleet if you can recruit them, but weakens the Quarians.

Comment: Caution about letting the Destiny Ascension...descend. Saving it gives you 70 pts in miltary strength versus the 25 you get for the Admiral. Remember, the Asari are the most technologically advanced race in the galaxy (minus the Reapers, of course).

Comment: I found a Googledoc with much more precise documentation: [Thanks, Chattone of Reddit!](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sy6kZVuOfVQDiXf07hvCtgX2mf305W_uCT9IvA8kj70/preview?sle=true#bookmark=id.mn7wdrqgxc8u)

Comment: Also Mass Effect: Infiltration, android game, is another sources as intel gathered and game completion can be uploaded and converted to war assets.

Comment: According to this [link](https://screenrant.com/mass-effect-legendary-edition-everything-carries-over-decisions-level-character/), UNC: Rogue VI mission result is also passed from ME1 to ME2, so that might have some impact on the game. I'm playing ME1 right now so I can't tell what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The Asari Matriarch/Bartender on Illium in ME2 is

> Liara's father

and will grant you Asari Commandos for 25 TMS if you make the right choices.

If you've never punched the reporter in any of the games you get 5 extra TMS for the Paragon interrupt in ME3.