# Is there Mass Effect 2 "ultimate playthrough" in regards to Mass Effect 3 import?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2

If I start a Mass Effect 2 game from scratch, keeping in mind that the save is ultimately intended for import to Mass Effect 3, where I'd want to have the best available resources (e.g skills, equipment, available crew members), which decisions should I keep in mind?

For example, I know I should have as many teammates survive the final mission as possible, but are there other missions I should try to complete one way over the other?

Which DLC, if any, should I play/avoid?

Comment: What are you really asking? What's the goal you're shooting for? The effect you want it to have on ME3 largely drives what you do in ME2. If your goal is "see as much as possible", then the simple answer is do every mission, every DLC, and keep every character alive. In short, I don't know what "ultimate playthrough" means.

Comment: Well, I wan't to have the most benefits from the playthrough (skills, equipment, available members, etc). I'll update my question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Best available ME3 setup? You'll need to go all the way back to ME1.  You can't have the ultimate Mass Effect play through without playing ME1.

1. Beat ME 1 on Normal (This unlocks Hardcore and ups the level cap)
2. Beat ME 1 on Hardcore (This unlocks Insanity)
3. Beat ME 1 on Insanity with all DLC getting to max level completing every mission and quest.

> Save Wrex too. You'll lose Mordin in ME3, but War Asset wise it's a better deal.

This gives the best setup for ME2.

4. Beat ME2 on any difficulty (This increases the level cap)
5. Beat ME2 on any difficulty again with all DLC getting to max level completing every mission and quest. Keep all squad members and
   crew members alive.

That should give you the best possible setup.

[Here's a short list of ME1 and ME2 decisions that can effect war assets in ME3.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54541/21097)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Assuming I play on the PS3, which ME1 never came out to, is there an alternative?

Comment: Short version: Do everything possible. There is no side-quest or DLC that will actually remove skills/equipment/members from you.

Comment: @JohnoBoy  see edit :)

Comment: I'm not convinced that saving Wrex puts you ahead overall on war assets.

Comment: Exhibit A: *Hardcore* gaming =)